# Mobile Redirect with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this redirect, and it works great. However, I want the user to be able to access the desktop site when they request it via a link on the external mobile site at `m.flyeurova.com`. How can I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isMobile = function() {
       //console.log("Navigator: " + navigator.userAgent);
       return /(iphone|ipod|ipad|android|blackberry|windows ce|palm|symbian)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
     };

    if(isMobile()) {
        window.location.href = "http://m.flyeurova.com/";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you  *not* do this.  User-agent sniffing isn't reliable, and even if it were, you have a lot of different devices with different capability.

Comment: You mean not do it this way, or generally not redirect the user at all?

Comment: He means do not do it this way. You could check out something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to check for different features that would only be available on a mobile device. Unless you have completely different features on your mobile side, another thing you could look into is a responsive design and just keep everyone on the same site, which can be pretty easily accomplished with something like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: I mean, do not redirect the user at all, for all the reasons Andrew just pointed out.